# Pass by reference in c array

Tags: c, arrays

Hi i want to ask about why i need to use printf("\n%d",x); instead of printf("\n%d",*x);?
Thank you very much

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define totalnum 8
void display(int **);
int main()
{
    int marks[totalnum]={55,65,75,85,90,78,95,60};
    printf("The marks of student A are:");  
    display(marks);
    return 0;
}
void display(int *x)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<totalnum;i++)
    printf("\n%d",x);
}
```

Comment: Hint: check the data types. but your code and usage doesn't look proper.

Comment: The prototype and definition of `display()` do not match.

Comment: There are several (obscure) differences between the two versions of display()  However, using int [] in the prototype is not a clear method .  better to use int * as that is clear.  Then both versions should use: printf("\n%d",x[i]);  as it is (almost) always better to not change the passed by value parameter(s).

Comment: What's up with the Stealth edit, taking someone's code in their answer and putting it in your question? Don't do that. Do DO a rollback, or I will. That is not considered fair; it's called "dirty pool". Edit: Never mind about you doing a rollback, I did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your looking for something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define totalnum 8

void display(int *);  //Typ is 'int *' NOT 'int **'
int main() {

    int marks[totalnum] = {55,65,75,85,90,78,95,60};

    printf("The marks of student A are:");
    display(marks);

    return 0;

}

void display(int *x) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < totalnum; i++) {
        printf("\n%d",*x);  //Prints the value
        x++;  //increments the pointer
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to ask what is the difference between your code and this code

Comment: '/* lab10_3.c pass by reference*/
   #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define totalnum 8
void display(int []);
int main()
{
 int marks[totalnum]={55,65,75,85,90,78,95,60};
 printf("The marks of student A are:"); 
 display(marks);
 return 0;
}
void display(int x[])
{
 int i;
 for(i=0;i<totalnum;i++)
 printf("\n%d",x[i]);
}'

Comment: @Jake In your Code your just printing the address of the first element of the array. In my Code i print all values of the array.

Comment: Sorry i have another code now updated plz check again plz THANK YOU i updated it in the question thanks

Comment: @Jake In the first one you pass the address of the first element of your array and print the address x times(x elements of the array). In the second example you pass the full array and you go through the values with the loop and you're printing all values of the array.

Answer (score 2):

There is no pass by reference in C. The array decays to a pointer in the display function which you declared wrongly as `int **` instead of `int *` - Compiler should have given you a warning at least about this:

http://ideone.com/R3skNj

This is how your `display` function should be like:

```
void display(int *x) 
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < totalnum; i++) {
        printf("\n%d",*(x+i)); // or printf("\n%d",x[i]);
    }
}
```